# Can i adjust Avid Elixir R SL hose angle without bleeding?

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I would like to adjust the angle of the brake hose coming from the caliper. I think this can be done by moving this part which should is called banjo i think.

[image: Banjo]

I would imagine I would need to loosen the bigger nut on the other side of the caliper and move the banjo?
[image: banjo nut]

Will I need to do a bleed after this? Only other info i found on this is here: https://www.mtbr.com/threads/avid-elixir-crs-banjo-adjustment-question.446453/
but it does not answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-do-i-bleed-avid-elixir-brakes - After a lot of trial and error with plenty of frustration, I found a simpler and reliable way to bleed them. First remove them from the bike, then throw them in the bin and install Shimano's. Great brake - when they worked.

Comment: Hehe is it that bad? They worked fine until this point. I am looking to bleed them myself for the first time in the near future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no experience with this model in particular, but I've performed the operation you describe several times without issue. The general technique is as Criggie outlines: slowly loosen the bolt until you can get the thing to move. You're only going to introduce air into the system if you loosen the bolt so much as to have a gap in the seal. Don't try to be extra safe by attempting to rotate the fitting at a high clamping force level--you risk tearing the seal. Loosen it a decent amount.

Even if you do introduce some air, it will only be a tiny amount. Assuming you have a bleed kit on the way, that's a manageable issue.

Comment: This may be obvious but worth mentioning: take care to NOT press the brake lever while the screw is lose to lessen the probability of introducing air in the system.

Comment: @MaplePanda thanks! would it help if i positioned the caliper on top (for example flipped the bike) ? Or is it better to have it on bottom?

Comment: @KarelPrdel No difference. You’re overthinking it. It’s a 2 second procedure. Loosen until you can rotate the fitting with some force, reposition to your liking, then retighten. Done!

Answer (score 2):

If there is no clear answer, personally I'd try giving it a go.

Backing the bolt off too much will allow air in and fluid out, but if you could undo the bolt slowly while applying some light-medium rotation to the fitting, it may move without loosing pressure.  Too much rotational pressure risks any seals.

Doing a bleed is relatively simple if you have the equipment, and will be necessary at sometime in the future.  Don't be scared of trying a bleed.

Comment: Thanks, then i will wait until I have my bleed kit before i attempt this. 

If I can have another question, I have heard here https://youtu.be/nnrP6u2p0IE?t=511 
that when changing the pads and pushing the pistons in, when encountering a lot of resistance, you should undo the bleed screw on the lever. The video shows shimano levers and horizontal position, so the bleed screw is pointing upwards. Can I do this on Avid elixir levers? The screw is pointed almost parallel to the hose so I am not sure how would i rotate the lever. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KarelPrdel that's a separate question, and I have no specific experience with that model.  Generally the bleed screw has to be at the very top of the system so air will rise to that point.